# Split polygon by polygon

Tags: r, polygon, splitting, sf

I have a polygon which I want to split using overlapping polygons in order to create 3 polygons (with the original attributes)
How can i achieve it using R ?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: probably `sf::st_intersection`

Comment: I've tried st_intersection but it doesn't divide the polygon. Instead it generates the same geometry everytime it overlaps the other polygons (in this case I ended up with 5 polygons)

Comment: Can you put together a reprex, I think your q is fair but it's hard to do this stuff without an example. Any chance you can subset out the relevant rows, save as rds or write to gpkg and share?

Answer (score 1):

For sure you just need to do an `st_intersection` like:

```
st_intersection(pol1, pol2)
```

If you get a 5 features polygon is because your pol1 is overlaping five "colored" polygons. If you are looking for 3 polygon result, you should just dissolve blue/green polygons and yellow/pinky ones bufore. You can do it by assign them a unique ID, `group_by` that ID and `summarize` them.